# Delete rows for which there is a duplicate in column 1

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have a table in Excel (columns A to J).

I want to delete any rows where there is a duplicate value in column A (this column should only have unique strings).

This is the code I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
Sub RD()

Dim rg As Range
 
Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

rg.RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), xlYes

End Sub
```

This version of excel doesn't seem to require me to write 'column' or 'header' in the penultimate line (they pop up though). Get a syntax error when I try to add this.

Comment: There are only `10` columns from `A` to `J`, which doesn't matter since you want to remove duplicates based only on the first column, so you have to replace the array with a simple `1`. If you would want to remove duplicates based on columns 1, 2, 4, and 7 you could use `VBA.Array(1, 2, 4, 7)`. The `VBA` is ensuring a zero-based array, while the `Array` function is producing a variant array. The third condition is if you create your own array with e.g. `Dim arr As Variant: Redim arr(0 to 1): arr(0) = 1: arr(1) = 3`, then you would have to use `(arr)`. Note the necessary parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicate value from `column A`, you almost write the current procedure, and replace your line with the following and it will work:

```
rg.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```